# Given elements of this VBA function not giving me Max number

Tags: vba

Hey guys I am trying to find the Max number from 3 given numbers in VBA, but it's not giving me what I won't. I know there are many function to get me there, like pre-built ones. But can u tell me exactly why this one won't function. It's for my school, no idea what to do. Doesn't seem to go past B parameter.

```
Function Max(A As Integer, B As Integer, C As Integer) As Integer
Max = A
If Max < B Or B > C Then
Max = B
ElseIf A < C Or B < C Then
Max = C
Else
Max = 0
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the maximum of three values by just checking each value in turn.

- Assume the first is the highest to start with.
- Then, if the current highest is less than the second, replace it *with* the second.
- Then do the same with the third.

The code for that would go something like this:

```
Function MaxOf3(num1 As Integer, num2 As Integer, num3 As Integer) As Integer
    MaxOf3 = num1
    If MaxOf3 < num2 Then MaxOf3 = num2
    If MaxOf3 < num3 Then MaxOf3 = num3
End Function
```